# Accessing Google Docs in ios

Tags: ios, ios5, google-docs

I am trying to access the Google docs by using following example on Github :- http://clearproxy.pl/index.php?q=aHR0cHM6Ly9naXRodWIuY29tL2FzdWdheWE%3D

Following is the error that i am facing while trying to login in the account can anyone  please tell me why i am getting this error:-

serviceBase: objectFetcher: failedWithStatus:403 data:GData`ServiceForbiddenException`403.4 SSL required
Terminating in response to SpringBoard's termination.

Thanks.

Comment: What URL you are using to access the google docs??

Comment: Hello, i have used the client library as provided by google and url is handled by that library

Comment: See the error which you are getting is because of one reason only: the user is using http instead of https.. so you can check for the same in your app..

Comment: sure i will check it. But is there any code available to access the google docs in our application? It will be very helpful

Comment: I guess you will have to use any google API for that...you will have to do a bit RnD for that..